# Why can't I add a constraint when creating the table?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `CHARSET` 
   (
    CHARSET_CODE varchar(15), 
    CHARSET_DESCRIPTION varchar(50), 
    APP_REGI_DATE date, 
    APP_UPD_DATE date, 
    CREATED_BY varchar(20), 
    CREATION_DATE date, 
    UPDATED_BY varchar(20), 
    UPDATE_DATE date, 
    LOCALE_CODE varchar(20),
    ADD constraint PK_80 PRIMARY KEY (CHARSET_CODE)

   ) ;
```

Giving me a red pointer on the last line where i am trying to add constraint.

Comment: What is the error? (Try hovering over the highlight.)

Comment: @Richard just needed to remove the 'ADD'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE CHARSET
(
    CHARSET_CODE varchar(15), 
    CHARSET_DESCRIPTION varchar(50), 
    APP_REGI_DATE date, 
    APP_UPD_DATE date, 
    CREATED_BY varchar(20), 
    CREATION_DATE date, 
    UPDATED_BY varchar(20), 
    UPDATE_DATE date, 
    LOCALE_CODE varchar(20),
    CONSTRAINT PK_80 PRIMARY KEY (CHARSET_CODE)
) ;
```

Remove `ADD` in your query and run it. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. You should remove the **ADD** keyword used before the constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE CHARSET 
( CHARSET_CODE varchar(15), 
CHARSET_DESCRIPTION varchar(50), 
APP_REGI_DATE date, 
APP_UPD_DATE date, 
CREATED_BY varchar(20), 
CREATION_DATE date, 
UPDATED_BY varchar(20), 
UPDATE_DATE date, 
LOCALE_CODE varchar(20), 
constraint PK_80 PRIMARY KEY (CHARSET_CODE));
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ADD` before contstraint, that should do the trick.

```
CREATE TABLE `CHARSET` (
    CHARSET_CODE varchar(15), 
    CHARSET_DESCRIPTION varchar(50), 
    APP_REGI_DATE date, 
    APP_UPD_DATE date, 
    CREATED_BY varchar(20), 
    CREATION_DATE date, 
    UPDATED_BY varchar(20), 
    UPDATE_DATE date, 
    LOCALE_CODE varchar(20),
    CONSTRAINT PK_80 PRIMARY KEY (CHARSET_CODE)
);
```